# Design to access elements of object owner

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Let's say I have two classes:

```
Class A {
  B b;
  Foo bar;
}

Class B {
// some stuff
}
```

Since an object of type A owns an object of type B, some stuff of B could be accessed by A. What would be a good design, if an object of type B has to has access to it's owning object (of type A)? E.g. if I have an object of type B and want to get the bar value of the object it is a member of.

Would it be good practise to add a reference to A to B everytime a B is created?Or some kind of delegate pattern?

Comment: I did punt an answer but I don't think it fits the requirements. But could you be more detailed on those please? Upvote in advance, in good faith.

Comment: Basically, if I have an object of type B I want to ask it "Do you have a master? And if so whats his 'bar' value?" I need an elegant way to say an object of type B to which A it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way would be using a parent pointer in your class B:

```
class A {
 A():b(this){}
 B b;
 Foo bar;
};

class B {
 B(A *parent=0)
 :p_parten(parent){}
 // some stuff
 void func(){
    if (p_parent)
      p_parent->bar.something();
 }
 A *p_parent;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply want to pass a reference or pointer to A into B's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If A depends B and B depends A at the same time this is called Circular Dependency. It indicates bad design but as I experienced you can't avoid it sometimes.

If this is a minimized version of something you will use in a big project I would advice you to think why B needs A since A seems your manager class. 
And move that shared part of A in to a seperate class lets call it C than pass C to B instead A.

If you have inclusion problems use "forward declaration" to declare A in B's header file.